# Strange iptables rules redirecting traffic to host I don't recognize

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, hacking

I never really managed my iptables config and went with the defaults. Today I had internet connection errors and in my attempts to fix this issue I checked my ipconfigs table. I found these strange ipconfigs rules for INPUT:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  main.macht.org       anywhere             tcp spt:123
ACCEPT     udp  --  main.macht.org       anywhere             udp spt:ntp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  static.253.144.69.159.clients.your-server.de  anywhere             tcp spt:123
ACCEPT     udp  --  static.253.144.69.159.clients.your-server.de  anywhere             udp spt:ntp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  spacys.de            anywhere             tcp spt:123
ACCEPT     udp  --  spacys.de            anywhere             udp spt:ntp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  195.50.171.101       anywhere             tcp spt:123
ACCEPT     udp  --  195.50.171.101       anywhere             udp spt:ntp
```

and for OUTPUT:

```
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             main.macht.org       tcp dpt:123
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             main.macht.org       udp dpt:ntp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             static.253.144.69.159.clients.your-server.de  tcp dpt:123
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             static.253.144.69.159.clients.your-server.de  udp dpt:ntp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             spacys.de            tcp dpt:123
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             spacys.de            udp dpt:ntp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             195.50.171.101       tcp dpt:123
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             195.50.171.101       udp dpt:ntp
```

I don't recognize `spacys.de, static.253.144.69.159.clients.your-server.de, main.macht.org, 195.50.171.101`.

What is happening here? Is my traffic being redirected to these addresses? If so does this mean I've been hacked and that the hacker has root access to my system (how else would he be able to change ipconfigs settings?)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Those are not redirects, merely ACCEPTS. There is no such thing as "default" iptables rules, so someone added them. Is your computer hosted? Anyway, they are just NTP (Network Time Protocol) ports, and so assume related somehow to that service.

Comment: But yes, if your listing is complete, you will definitely have internet connection issues, as there is no return path for normal packets. You did not list your OUTPUT chain default rule, so can not tell for that side of it.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. The computer is not hosted. I since did a iptables flush with `iptables -F`, rebooted my system and recognized that similar entries were made to iptables. I thought about which program I installed would change those settings and came up with the nordvpn client. I removed it, flushed iptables again and rebooted my system. No new entries were made after reboot. So I think this might have been a bug (or misconfiguration by me) of the nordvpn client.